# How to replace a HTML input control with its Value using jquery?

Tags: html, replace, controls

I have HTML in a variable using following code.

```
var htmlTables = '<div><table><tr><td><input id="txtweek2" name="txtweek2" style="width:100px" class="form-control timebox" value=""></td>
<td><input id="txtweek3" name="txtweek3" style="width:100px" class="form-control timebox" value="test value"></td></tr></table></div>';
```

Now I need to replace the input controls with its value it is having, and i need output as below.

```
var htmlTables = '<div><table><tr><td></td>
    <td>test value</td></tr></table></div>';
```

I tried with below code.

```
 $(htmlTables).find('input').each(function () {
                alert(this.value);
                this.replaceWith(this.value);                
                //$(this).replaceWith("test");
```

Kindly let me know the possibilities. The HTML i provided is just a sample. I have more div, table, tr, td, center etc in the html string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you output the code in the htmlTables variable, you can then use jQuery to replace the input fields by their values with this code:

```
jQuery('#txtweek2').replaceWith(jQuery('#txtweek2').val());
jQuery('#txtweek3').replaceWith(jQuery('#txtweek3').val());
```

You can play with it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cckumk8o/

If you do not know the id and the content is generated dynamically, you could use the class of the replaced elements like this:

```
var count=jQuery('.timebox').size();
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
   jQuery('input.timebox:eq(0)').replaceWith(jQuery('input.timebox:eq(0)').val());
}
```

It is also available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/y1qemn5b/

Comment: Thanks.. But its not only two input fields available. Its builded dynamically, and most of the time i dont know the id!

Comment: Hi... Thanks. The code you updated helped me a lot.  I changed some logic in my page and achieved my required result. :)